# Retrieve the minimum value of a column from the max value of another column

Tags: sql, hive

I have a hive table t1 that looks like this:

```
ID   Score1    score2  
1     4         11  
1     5         12  
1     5         13  
2     3         14  
2     3         15  
2     2         12  
2     2         11  
3     6         10  
3     6         11  
3     6         12
```

I want for each ID, to select the max value of score1, and if the max value exists more than once, then from the rows that contain max(score1) I want to get min(score2).

So, I want the minimum score2 of the maximum score1 rows, the results should be something like this

```
ID    Score1    score2  
1     5         12  
2     3         14  
3     6         10
```

Most of the ideas I have turn this to be a very complicated query, and I think there is a simple solution for it that I am not able to find yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:mysql], but the question seems to be about Hive. Please tag your question accurately, because people watch tags, and you want to attract the attention of the people best able to answer your question.

Comment: Who confirmed this is for Hive? Why was MySQL removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by score1 asc, score2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, min(score2)
from table1 t
inner join (
   select id, max(score1) maxscore1 group by id
    )  d on t.id = d.id and t.score1 = d.maxscore1
group by t.id
having count(*) > 1 # if the max value exists more than once
```

an alternative query, if the db does support "analyic functions", is

```
select
     id, min(score2)
from (
      select id, score1, score2
            , count(case when score1 = max(score1) over(partition by id) then 1 end) count_max
      from table1
      ) d
where count_max > 1 -- if the max value exists more than once
group by
     id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Z.ID, Z.SCORE1, MIN(SCORE2) AS SCORE2
FROM
(SELECT A.ID, A.SCORE FROM
YOUR_TABLE A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID, MAX(SCORE1) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY ID) B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.SCORE1 = B.SCORE1
GROUP BY A.ID, A.SCORE
HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
) Z
INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE C
ON Z.ID = C.ID AND Z.SCORE1 = C.SCORE1
GROUP BY Z.ID, Z.SCORE1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

SELECT ID, score1, MIN(score2) AS score2
FROM (
  SELECT score1, score2, ID
  FROM (
    SELECT score1, score2, ID
    FROM MyTable
    QUALIFY RANK OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY score1 DESC) > 1
  ) src
  QUALIFY  COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY ID) > 1
) src
GROUP BY 1,2

Sorry, writing this from my phone...can't format it well, there may be syntax errors too.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Hive does not support `qualify`.

Comment: You can rewrite it without a QUALIFY,  using an outer SELECT, aliasing the derived column, and then using a WHERE clause.